# en laravel puedo llamar una vista desde @extends('layouts.admin') que sea del @extends('layouts.app')

Tags: html, html5, laravel, laravel-5, vistas

En la vista de admin llamo a la otra vista de la siguiente manera

```
<li><a title="Crear Usuario" 

href="/register" -> Para llamar el usuario

><span class="mini-sub-pro">Crear Usuario</
```

Answer (score 0):

Si se puede, podría quedar de la siguiente manera.

views/layouts/app.blade.php:

```html
<html>
    <body>
        <h1>Vengo desde el layout app</h1>
        <div class="miContenido">
            @yield('contenido')
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

views/layouts/admin.blade.php:

```html
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('contenido')
    <h2>Vengo desde el layout admin</h2>
    <div class="panelAdministrador">
        @yield('panelAdministrador')
    </div>
@endsection
```

views/admin/index.blade.php:

```html
@extends('layouts.admin')
@section('panelAdministrador')
    <h3>vengo desde el archivo index.blade.php</h3>
@endsection
```

El resultado seria el siguiente:

```html
<html>
    <body>
        <h1>Vengo desde el layout app</h1>
        <div class="miContenido">
            <h2>Vengo desde el layout admin<h2>
            <div class="panel introducir el código aquí Administrador">
                <h3>vengo desde el archivo index.blade.php</h3>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Debes tomar en cuenta que podrías mandar a llamar `@yield('contenido')` desde el archivo index.blade.php